# adding uitextfield or (textentry box with keyboard) in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitextfield

I am recently working on sprite kit to create a simple game where user input name as identity and moves forward to play game and has option to edit name or replace name. 
Which is best option to use `uitextfield`: in `skscene` or `viewcontroller`? Or any other solutions?

I had tried with `uitextfield` adding in `skscene` but got memory issue (since i called scene from `viewwilllayoutSubview`

```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    let scene =
        NameEntryScene(size:CGSize(width: 1024, height: 718))
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
```

which I followed stackoverflow others answer to add `uitextfield` in gamesence at `didMove(to view: SKView)`.

Also created `uitextfield` in `viewcontroller` and pass its instance all over the gamesence with action of `isHidden` true and false to remove memory issue, which worked but I can't work like this if i have many `uitextfield`'s at various postions.

Any suggestion and help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i had the same problem, i fixed it by getting username in view controller and pass the name as SKLableNode in GameScene. (Im showing players name which i get in view controller by SKLableNode)
if it is not necessary to let people change name in game scene, it's better to use viewController, and have some pages like edit profile.

Comment: @Mina - you mean a sequence of viewcontroller - gamescene - viewcontroller where tranisition always occure between viewcontrollers. Have you used those with notification pattern?
And my requirement is to change name during game using gamescene which have (2 or more) uitextfield.

Comment: if you need to change name during game you can also use UIAlertView
i suggest it because i couldn't find a good way to use UITextField in game scene. some times if it is possible, it's better to have a deeper look to the game strategy and standards of game development in swift. most of the game which are use textfield and have data entry in game are cross platforms not native. so in iOS games must finds better way. i would be glad to be informed if you had any achievement.

Comment: @mina ok thanks i will try with alterView. and let you know i got over this. 
If you can suggest me the best reading article or help you have collected during the time you faced the issue. Thanks.

Comment: there are some thread about UITextField in SpriteKit Like these ones : 
[Creating Text Fields in SpriteKit](http://girasoli.org/creating-text-fields-in-spritekit/) and [Adding UITextField in SpriteKit](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7424) but i have some problems with constraints. i will find the thread which totally rejected using UIViews Objects in GameScene and send it to you.
Good Luck

Comment: adding textfield in altert(custom view from xib) actually worked for me.          I added custom view through delegate added to 'SKView'. passed textfield value to game scene through userDefaults.                                                                 But the node element are still active in the backgroundView.  And I am pushed back to previous Scene.

Comment: what do you mean by previous scene?
please explain it clearly

Comment: i have sequence of of SKScene 1. GameSelect then 2. Game 1... I have option node on 'Game 1' whenever i click that one the popover arrives at 'gameselet'

Comment: is it a level up game? i mean you change your scene for up level? if you change your scene by 'SKTransition' there is no problem with Nodes, because when you move to another scene the engine handle the previous scene by it self.
but there is a trick when you move from viewController to scene.
you must remove viewController objects before transition.
and if you only have one game scene and your other pages are something like menus and settings and... it's better to change them to UIViewController.
it will be helpful if you post some codes.

Comment: Yes, its level up game.  I tried to present scene during level up. I actually now present viewController instead of view and it worked well. If I still encounter more problem in path i will post code as well. Thank you for you continuous help.